# Image rendering on HTML5 canvas on iPhone 5 running iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, html5-canvas, mobile-safari

canvasOn a web page in a mobile web application I am developing, I have a fileinput control that is used to take a picture with a mobile device camera.  The image from the camera is then drawn onto an HTML5 canvas object on the same page.

The issue I am having is that if the web application is run on an iPhone 5 running iOS 7 (in the Safari web browser), the image appears extremely distorted.  Specifically, the image appears to be vertically squished when drawn on the canvas.  If the same web application is run on an Android device, no distortion is seen.

In previous versions of iOS and on iOS devices prior to iPhone 5, some vertical squishing was seen (although not as bad as this), and a jquery plugin named megapixel-image.js could be used to correct the vertical squishing.  This tool unfortunately is not compatible with iOS 7.

Is this related to image subsampling in Safari or something else?  What can be done to correct this?  I obviously cannot have my users see this distorted image.  Any mobile web app developer who wants to use the camera and HTML5 canvas is going to run into this, so a solution is mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

megapixel-image.js does handle this correctly.  I found I was passing some parameters to the plugin incorrectly, causing it not to work.  My thanks to Ray Nicholus for his assistance with  this issue.